# Why is the spin magnetic moment for Ni$^{2+}$ given as 1.7 Bohr magnetons in some references?

Tags: atomic-physics, magnetic-moment

I read some theoretical articles concerning Ni-O system, where Ni sits at the center of the octahedron formed by O. The calculated magnetic moment on the Ni sites are about 1.7. And these articles said that this is the typical magnetic moment of d8 Ni$^{2+}$. I think according to $\mu=\sqrt(n(n+2))$ where $n$ is the number of unpaired electrons, d8 Ni$^{2+}$ should have 2 unpaired electrons and $\mu=2.8$. Can anyone give me some help on it?

Comment: Which references?